# How can I write a list of words in a char?

Tags: c

I'm working at a dictionary and I need to write a list of words which are then replaced by other words. I just started coding not a long time ago, so I'm sorry for my inaptitude!

```
//working 
char word[] = { "hello" };
char replace[] = { "salut" };

//not working 
char word[] = { "hello", "what" };
char replace[] = { "salut", "quoi" };
```

When I try to compile the second part, where I've written "not working", the IDE gives me the following errors: "too many initializer values", "too many initializers". Although, the "working" part is working as expected.

I will be waiting for some solutions to/advices for my code... Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's really not clear what it is you are trying to do. If you had a line of code that worked, what would come next? For example, how would you access the second word?

Comment: @Amurg  Define it in a 2D array to make it work

Comment: For the list you can also use 2D array as char word[2][20]. There are many ways to have string array in C.

Comment: The full code is replacing the char word[] with char replace[] in a text. It's a dictionary more or less. It's working if there's only one word inside the char, but if there are multiple words it cannot be compiled... I was thinking that maybe the second word from char word[] would be linked to the second word from char replace[] by some reasons, I am really not sure about it...

Comment: An array of `char` can be initialized with a C string literal. `char word[] = "hello";` is enough, no need for brackets. If you want an array of C strings, then you need to add another dimension.

Comment: I've tried with a 2D array and it compiled. But the problem is that only the first word was translated while the others ignored.

Comment: If that's the case, you should review the logic of what you're trying to accomplish. By doing this change (2D to 1D because it didn't work), you're causing it to not compile anymore, and it's not valid in C.

Comment: You should use [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation)

Answer (score 3):

you should be using array of pointers to intialize hte not working part .
That should be like `char *words[] = {"word1", "word2"} ;` 
That fixes the non working part but can you bit elaborate about your question

Edit1:
This is sample code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(char argc,char *argv[])
{
  char *words[2] = {"test","word"};
  printf("words[1] = %s , words[2] = %s \n", words[0], words[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

### This code returns output:

words[1] = test , words[2] = word

Can you post your error message / which  compiler you are using , which platform ?

Edit2:

Since You are having words as array of pointers , you have to check them properly in strstr if you intend to use it.

### Here is the example :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{ 
    char str1[] = "practice makes perfect"; 
    char *str2[2] = {"practice", "perfect"}; 
    char* ptr1; 
    char *ptr2;

    ptr1 = strstr(str1, str2[0]);
    ptr2 = strstr(str1, str2[1]); 


    if (ptr1 != NULL ) { 
        printf("String %s found in %s\n",str2[0], str1); 
    } else
        printf("String not found\n");

    if (ptr2 != NULL) {
        printf("String %s found in %s\n", str2[1], str1); 
    } else
        printf("String not found\n");
    return 0; 
} 

Output:
String practice found in practice makes perfect
String perfect found in practice makes perfect
```

Comment: Are you sure this is correct, instead of a 2D array? Because an array of pointers store pointers that not necessarily were allocated.

Comment: @YuriJ the pointers point to string literals. Where a word is found which matches one pointed to by an element of the first array, the word is translated by the corresponding element of the other array. The dictionary words themselves are not modified, so are fine as string literals.

Comment: If initialization of an array is done at the time of declaration then the above code is fine . but 2d is cleaner way for someone who is getting started and if the input is dynamic , we should be using malloc/calloc .

Comment: I just tried your suggestion and I have the same issue I get when I'm trying to use a 2D array. The code will compile, but only the first word will be translated and the rest ignored in output.

Comment: can you pls post your code which is compiling to look at ? and also post if you see any errors ?

Comment: Code before posting the thread: https://shrib.com/#l0UY431ZwEViUAfEu7Si
Compiler: The C compiler used by Visual Studio

Comment: ok , check on your syntax of checking if word is present ? check the difference between ` word and word[0] and word/word[1]`

Comment: I didnt check the logic of your code, but the strstr accepts const char * but are you sure you are provding proper input to strstr ?

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm new to coding and have little idea what I'm doing. I try my best to understand anything and everything, but it's tough. And I really need this code to work...

Answer (score 0):

So I'm assuming you want to have two lists which are containing words from two different languages. Then when you're given some input text in english, you want to switch that text to second language by replacing words with the help of lists. If I'm right: then use pointers like the @cslrnr said.

```
char* english[] = {word1, word2, ...};
char* otherLanguage[] = {word1, word2, ...};
```

Comment: Maybe you forgot quotes around the words?

Comment: I've tried it. The code will compile, but only the first word in output will be translated and the rest ignored.

Comment: Define the length inside [] brackets.